# SQL Bulk Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a csv file that is sent to me. I have put the file into Notepad++ which shows the ROWTERMINATOR as CRLF. This means that I use \r\n as my ROWTERMINATOR in SQL correct?

This is the file format (CRLF at the end of each row):

```
2020/02/10 03:00:00,2020/02/11 02:59:59,2
101,1,5,1,7,10950,0,10950,0,1429
101,1,5,2,7,28878,5500,28878,0,0
101,1,5,3,4,9525,1200,9525,0,0
101,1,5,4,1,7686,0,7686,0,0
101,1,5,7,3,9094,1300,9094,0,0
```

I essentially need to pull the date from the first cell and then ignore the rest of that row, which I have done:

```
SET @sql =
'BULK INSERT #date  
FROM ' + '''' + @fileName + '''' + '
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 1,
    LASTROW = 1,
    ROWTERMINATOR = ' + '''' + ',' + '''' + ',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ' + '''' + ',' + '''' + ',
    CODEPAGE=' + '''' + '65001' + '''' + ',
    KEEPNULLS
)'
```

Then pull the remaining 5 rows of data, which isn't working because it is wrapping all of the data into one row:

```
SET @sql =
'BULK INSERT #fileColumns  
FROM ' + '''' + @fileName + '''' + '
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ' + '''' + ',' + '''' + ',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ' + '''' + '\r\n' + '''' + ',
    CODEPAGE=' + '''' + '65001' + '''' + ',
    KEEPNULLS
)'
```

I have also tried \n as a ROWTERMINATOR which gives me the last 4 rows because the first row of data is being wrapped into the first.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is related to the first row having mutliple columns. The way I would do this is import into a table without and fieldterminator. So everything goes into a single column, then use T-SQL to shred out what you need.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing since I cannot find anything else that will work. I will post the logic I used as an answer here in a minute.

Comment: Basically a reggaed right file (where number of fields are different on each row) can not be imported using `BULK INSERT` using normal means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really like the way I had to do this, but it works:

```
SET @sql =
'BULK INSERT #fileColumns  
FROM ' + '''' + @fileName + '''' + '
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    ROWTERMINATOR = ' + '''' + '\n' + '''' + ',
    CODEPAGE=' + '''' + '65001' + '''' + ',
    KEEPNULLS
)'

EXEC (@sql)

WITH Split AS (
SELECT  Column1,
        Split.value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber
    FROM #fileColumns
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Column1, ',') AS Split
)

SELECT  [1] AS ProfitCenterId,
        [2] AS CheckTypeId,
        [3] AS MealPeriodId,
        [4] AS TenderId,
        [5] AS NumberOfTenders,
        [6] AS TenderAmount,
        [7] AS TipAmount,
        [8] AS ReceivedAmount,
        [9] AS BreakageAmount,
        [10] AS ChangeGiven
        FROM Split
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX(value)
            FOR RowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
        ) AS piv
```

Definitely not pretty, but it will do.